# ¿Cómo usar la función postMessage?

Tags: javascript

He subido un archivo a un servidor de hostinger con el siguiente código:

```
<body bgcolor="black"></body>
<script>
  onmousedown = function(e) {
    window.postMessage(prompt("Enter your message"),location.href)
  }
  window.onpostmessage = function(e) {
    if(e.origin==location.href) {
      alert(e.data)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Pero el problema es que cuando presiono el mouse y escribo el mensaje, la página no me envía una alerta diciéndome *"e.data"*.

¿Qué tengo que hacer para mejorar el archivo para que me envíe la alerta correctamente en cada ventana que tendrá que tener esa URL?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto *(try this)*

```
<body bgcolor="black"></body>
<script>
  onmousedown=function(e){
    window.postMessage(prompt("Enter your message"),location.href)
  }
  window.onmessage=function(e){
    if(e.origin==location.href){
      alert(e.data)
    }else{
      alert(e.origin+'!='+location.href)
    }
  }
</script>
```

### Correciones

- `onmessage` vs `onpostmessage`
- `else` --> `alert(e.origin+'!='+location.href)`

Comment: That code sends me an alert when I put a message, but if I open two windows in my computer, it doesn't send me two alerts. I need to send a message to all window in my hostinger server, but thanks for your helping.

Comment: The postMessage function is for comunicate between iframes in the same document: `otherIframe.postMessage(...)`. If you want to comunicate between tabs without using a backend you can use [Web workers](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/). If you want to comunicate via a back-end you can use ajax

Comment: How can I download a webworker? And, how can I use it?

Comment: Una buena explicación se puede encontrar acá: https://www.html5rocks.com/es/tutorials/workers/basics/

Comment: Me da un error:
"BlobBuilder is not defined."

Comment: Acá va un ejemplo más corto: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker El concepto es el mismo que leíste en el artículo de html5rocks

Comment: Algo hay mal, porque cuando ejecuto el SharedWorker y le añado un puerto no se me envian los mensajes.

Comment: Agrega otra pregunta con los detalles de lo que hiciste y vemos

Comment: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26593/c%C3%B3mo-se-usa-el-sharedworker

Answer (score 0):

Un par de cosas:

1. Trata de no poner los scripts fuera del body (técnicamente no es HTML válido).
2. No existe el evento `postmessage` el evento es `message`.

Tu código sería:

```
<body>
    <script>
    window.onmessage = function(e) {
      console.log(e.origin, e.data, location.href);
      if(e.origin === window.location.href) {
        alert(e.data);
      }
    }
    window.onmousedown = function() {
      window.postMessage(
        prompt("Enter your message"),
        window.location.href
      )
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Se envía el mensaje, pero luego no lo recibe.

This code sends the message, but after that, the html page doesn't send me an alert.

Comment: Are you running this in a `iframe/object`?. If the alert is not fired it means the `window.location.href` doesn't match. Try this code on [JSBin](https://jsbin.com) and see the behaviour.

Comment: The code doesn't work in jsbin, it doesn't send me any alert...