# ¿Cómo se usa el SharedWorker con el fin de hacer un chat?

Tags: javascript

Recientemente he estado probando la función postMessage, pero solo funciona dentro del documento. Entonces, Emilio me mostró que se hacía por SharedWorkers, entonces traté de activar un script en la misma carpeta, de manera que me lo leyese como un SharedWorker:

```
<body>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script>
document.body.style.backgroundColor="black"
worker=new SharedWorker("a.js")
worker.port.start()
worker.onmessage=function(e){console.log(e.data)}
worker.port.postMessage("An user has connected.")
onmousedown=function(e){if(e.button==0){worker.port.postMessage(prompt("Enter your message."))}}
</script>
</body>
```

Estuve probándolo y me dí cuenta de que a diferencia del Worker, los mensajes se supone que deberían enviarse a todos los scripts que ejecutan el "SharedWorker". Entonces, traté de usar un SharedWorker, de manera que me dí cuenta de que necesitaba un puerto como intermediario, y probé este código que aparece atrás y hay algo mal porque no me envía los mensajes a la consola cuando se envían a esta. La pregunta es, ¿Qué hay mal aquí? ¿Existe alguna manera de reparar el error?

Acá les dejo el código del script que hace de SharedWorker:

```
i=0
port={}
onconnect=function(event){
i++
port[i]
port[i].start()
port[i].addEventListener("message",function(event){function(event,port){
for(i in port){
port[i].postMessage(event.data+" from "+event.port)
}}})}
```

Ese era el código antiguo, ahora lo mejoré:
Este es el archivo chat7.js :

```
ports=[]
self.addEventListener("connect",function(event1){
port=event1.ports[0]
ports.push(port)
port.addEventListener("message",function(event2){
for(i in ports){
ports[i].postMessage(event2.data)}},false)
port.start()})
```

Este es el archivo chat7.htm :

```
<body>
<script>
document.body.style.backgroundColor="black"
worker=new SharedWorker("chat v7.js")
worker.port.start()
worker.port.addEventListener("message",function(event){console.log(event.data)},false)
worker.port.postMessage("An user has connected.")
onkeydown=function(e){if(e.keyCode==13){
worker.port.postMessage(prompt("Enter your message."))
}}
</script>
</body>
```

Esto está alojado en un subdominio de hostinger (esy.es), y lo he mejorado en el sentido de que cuando abro una serie de ventanas en un mismo ordenador, el "SharedWorker" me detecta cuando un usuario envía un mensaje al "SharedWorker", y distribuye el mensaje por todas las ventanas.

Pero existe un problema, el cual hace que cuando se envíen mensajes desde distintas computadoras, no se registren en ambas. ¿Qué tengo que hacer para que los mensajes se distribuyan por todas las computadoras?

Comment: ¿qué hay en a.js?

Comment: Le he añadido una función para que detecte si hay un mensaje y lo postee, pero no sé cómo hacer que mande las alertas.

Comment: @EmilioPlatzer Ya terminé la edicción de la pregunta con el fin de ser más conciso.

Comment: Dónde estará rosita...

Capaz y tenga novio...

T_T

Answer (score 0):

Este es un ejemplo:

```
//WebSharedWorkeds.js
function iniciar(){
    var boton=document.getElementById("boton");
    boton.addEventListener("click",enviar,false);

    trabajador=new SharedWorker("WebSharedWorkers-trabajador.js");
    trabajador.port.addEventListener("message",recibido,false);
    trabajador.port.addEventListener("error",error,false);
    trabajador.port.start();
}
function recibido(e){
    alert(e.data);
}
function enviar(){
    var nombre=document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    trabajador.port.postMessage(""+nombre);
    document.getElementById("nombre").value="";
    document.getElementById("nombre").focus();
}
function error(e){
    alert("Error: "+e.message+"\nArchivo: "+e.filename+"\nLinea: "+e.lineno+"\n");
}
window.addEventListener("load",iniciar,false);
```

Este es el HTML:

```
<!--HTML-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WebWorkers</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WebSharedWorkers.css" >
        <script type="text/javascript" src="WebSharedWorkers.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="cajaformulario">
            <form name="formulario">
                <p>Nombre: <br/><input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"> </p>
                <p> <input type="button" name="boton" id="boton" value="Enviar" ></p>
            </form>
        </section>
        <section id="cajadatos">
            <iframe id="iframe" src="WebSharedWorkers-iframe.html" width="500px" height="350px">
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

y el css:

```
/*WebSharedWorkers.css*/    
#cajaformulario{
        float:left;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #999999;
    }
    #cajadatos{
        float:left;
        width: 500px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #999999;
    }
    #cajadatos2{
        float:left;
        width: 400px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #999999;
    }
```

Comment: Lo he remodelado, sin embargo cuando conecto una nueva ventana no me deja escribir mensajes en la anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Acá hay un código que funciona para `a.js`

```
var ports=[];

self.addEventListener("connect",function(event1){
    var port = event1.ports[0];
    ports.push(port);
    port.addEventListener("message",function(event2){
        for(var i=0; i<ports.length; i++){
            ports[i].postMessage(event2.data)
        }
    },false);
    port.start();
})
```

En la variable ports se guardan los ports que se van conectando (para después mandar un mensaje a todos. Como es un array se itera con `for(i=0; i<lenght; i++)`. Agregué también `self` para el `connect`.

### el html:

Lo probé con éste html:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<input id=a_enviar autofocus>
<input id=enviar type=button value=enviar>
<pre id=mensajes>
</pre>
<pre id=errores style='background:red'>
</pre>
<script>
var worker=new SharedWorker("a.js")
worker.port.start()
worker.port.onmessage=function(e){
    mensajes.textContent+="\n"+e.data;
}
worker.port.onerror=function(e){
    errores.textContent+="\n"+e.data;
}
worker.port.postMessage("An user has connected.")
enviar.onclick=function(){
    worker.port.postMessage(a_enviar.value);
    a_enviar.value='';
    a_enviar.focus();
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Algo hay mal, porque los mensajes solo aparecen en una ventana.

Comment: ¿Qué navegador estás usando? Yo lo probé en Google Chrome

Comment: Yo igual, y la pestaña de "más" me aparece en blanco.

Comment: Ahí puse el .html con que lo estuve probando. Podrías fijarte si con ese te anda, quizás el problema esté en el .html. Lo probé en Chrome 53.0.2785.143 m

Comment: "a_enviar.focus()" is not a function.

Comment: ¿le habrás quitado el id a `<input id=a_enviar autofocus>`?

Comment: Personalmente prefiero que se envien los mensajes con solo presionar la tecla enter.

Comment: Obviamente yo también. Pero nos estamos concentrando en ver cómo funciona los SharedWorkes. Una vez que eso ande se puede concentrar en otras cosas. Un consejo. Antes de modificar otras cosas hay que intentar resolver el punto en el que estamos.

Comment: Copié tu html y no aparece ningún mensaje.

Comment: Mejoré tu código:
http://tatopatato.esy.es/chat%20v7.htm
Ahí está el chat, aunque sigue habiendo algo mal, ya que se comunica entre las ventanas solo si estas están en el mismo ordenador.

Comment: Esa es otra pregunta. Te aconsejo realizar otra pregunta en SO. Cuánto más concisa y concreta, más probabilidad de que más gente te ayude. También te aconsejo aceptar la mejor respuesta y votar todas las que te hayan servido. Esa es la manera de mostrarte agradecido.

Comment: No puedo hacer otra, ya que si la hago la eliminan por clonada, en lugar de eso si sabes como mejorar el chat que hize podrías poner un código.